# Site-relative datasource locations

Tags: multisite, datasource

We have a multisite setup, where `Shared Content` is stored in a node for each site as a sibling to the site frontpage.

For example:

```
- Website 1
-- Home
--- Some page
-- Shared Content
--- Contacts
- Website 2
...
```

In the above example, how would i use the `Contacts` folder as a DataSource Location in a TreeList or Multi List field etc.?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Would that work for you?

`ancestor-or-self::*[@@templateid='{website-root-template-id-here}']/*[@@templateid='{shared-content-template-id-here}']/*[@@templateid='{contacts-node-template-id-here}']`

This'll travel up the content tree to the nearest website root node (from any page) and then down to the respective Contacts node.